# How can I avoid my windows phone tile icon being used as an alpha mask?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am making a windows phone 8 app and I'm trying to make a nice tile for the start screen, so I opened my WMAppManifest.xml in Visual Studio, selected TemplateIconic and imported the desired image. My problem is that it's using my image as an alpha mask, so all the colours it has are simply transformed into white. I'd like to conserve all the colours from my image.

How can I avoid my tile icon being used as an alpha mask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **WMAppManifest.xml** and set **Tile Template** as `TemplateFlip`.

Comment: Even if I don't intend to have anything on the flip side?

Comment: Sure. The tile will not flip until you add something to the flip side. I use this template in all [my apps](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/publishers?publisherId=%25c5%2581ukasz%2BRejman&appId=3587a122-054d-4f43-a3b8-880bd515000a).

Comment: Ok, that does indeed work, but apparently TemplateFlip doesn't support the BackgroundColor tag... How do I set the background color for this kind of tile?

Comment: Your icon image has to have this color in background instead of transparency.

Comment: Ahh, it fills the entire tile in TemplateFlip?

Comment: Yes. It's up to you to make nice margins in the image to center your icon on the tile. Here, you can read about sizes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206971(v=vs.105).aspx